# View from DB2 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, db2, database-migration, sql-view

I'm attempting to move a view between DB2 and SQL Server.

```
CREATE VIEW msu.bad_bus_cnty_st_mstr 
AS 
  SELECT id, 
         bus_cnty_cntry_cd, 
         bus_st, 
         bus_zip 
  FROM   summit.mstr 
  WHERE  ( bus_cnty_cntry_cd, bus_st ) IN (SELECT cnty_cntry_cd, 
                                                  st 
                                           FROM   uhelp.cnty_cntry_cd 
                                           WHERE 
         cnty_cntry_descr LIKE '%invalid%');
```

The view works in DB2, but doesn't work with SQL Server because of the WHERE clause. Can I have a recommendation on how to rewrite this view to work with SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually helps to define what "doesn't work" means (e.g. what error did you get) and also to specify the version of SQL Server you are using.

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't support IN() with more than one clause. However you can re-write your view this way:

```
ALTER VIEW msu.bad_bus_cnty_st_mstr 
AS 
  SELECT id, 
         bus_cnty_cntry_cd, 
         bus_st, 
         bus_zip 
  FROM   summit.mstr AS mstr 
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
     SELECT 1
        FROM uhelp.cnty_cntry_cd 
        WHERE cnty_cntry_descr LIKE '%invalid%'
         AND cnty_cntry_cd = mstr.bus_cnty_cntry_cd
         AND st = mstr.bus_st
  );
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure bad_bus_cnty_st_mstr, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ','.
 is the error msg i receive in SQL2005.

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly? There is no comma on line 8. The only commas in my code are commas between the columns in the SELECT list. Did you add an extra trailing comma there perhaps?

Comment: sorry, that was the original error message I received (e.g., what "doesn't work" means)

Answer (score 0):

one way

```
CREATE VIEW msu.bad_bus_cnty_st_mstr 
AS 
  SELECT id, 
         bus_cnty_cntry_cd, 
         bus_st, 
         bus_zip 
  FROM   summit.mstr m
  WHERE  EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM   uhelp.cnty_cntry_cd  c
  WHERE c.cnty_cntry_descr LIKE '%invalid%'
  AND c.bus_cnty_cntry_cd = m.bus_cnty_cntry_cd
  AND c.st = m.bus_st)
```